# Sencha Touch with Nokia Mobile Phones

Tags: qt, mobile, nokia, sencha-touch, nokia-n8

Does anyone knows how to implement Sencha Touch with Nokia phones, Symbian operating system. As far as i make research i saw that it is possible to implement, there is a video with N8 implementation: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ERwS1sBRY-w

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sencha Touch is not officially supported on Symbian Devices.

> Sencha Touch is a cross-platform framework aimed at next generation, touch enabled, devices. It's currently compatible with Apple iOS 3+, Android 2.1+, and BlackBerry 6+ devices. Together these devices represent over 95% of current US mobile traffic.

As the video shows it may still be possible to point the Nokia web browser to a Sencha Touch mobile site and have it work properly.  The Youtube comments [link](http://gitorious.org/ofi-labs/x2/trees/master/webkit/senchatouchqtwebkit) to a git project that has a sample native Nokia app to get you started building Sencha Touch projects for Nokia. Something like [PhoneGap](http://www.phonegap.com/) may help you in deploying to Symbian devices.

Comment: I am actually using phoneGap with Sencha Touch for iphone. So, what i understand that i have to use QtWebKit + PhoneGap for Symbian phones right?

Comment: Technically no, PhoneGap for Symbian devices would have been built in QTWebKit. So, you shouldn't have to use QTWebKit unless you need to fix bugs or add features.  You will still need to have an environment to compile the PhoneGap project though.